# Django - How to test an application with millions of users

Tags: django, testing

I want to test a blog application with millions of users particularly where each posts have number of views that is visited by users. Although I tried to login with different browser for each users,its not efficient. How should I test users to login and try this application?

**Requirements**

- Counts must be real time or near-real time. No daily or hourly aggregates.
- Each user must only be counted once.
- The displayed count must be within a few percentage points of the actual tally.
- The system must be able to run at production scale and process events within a few seconds of their occurrence.

Although I tried to login with different browser for each users,its not efficient.

Comment: You don't really show a system that you apparently tested with multiple browsers?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want tiny framework like [locust](https://docs.locust.io/en/stable/installation.html) ?
It works well for performance tests